# How do I create an empty immutable Scala map in Java?

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, immutability

This should be an obvious one but I've not yet found an elegant solution. For various reasons, I need to create an immutable Scala map (scala.collection.immutable.Map from Scala 2.10), but I can only write Java code. How do I do this?

Comment: He wants to create a **scala** map in java, not the opposite.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wild guess - here goes nothing:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map$.MODULE$.<…, …>empty()
```

Comment: Do you really need to go through `MODULE` by hand? As far as I know there are forwarder static methods that already do this. Can't check right now though, I have no compiler at hand.

Comment: My bad, you do need to access `Map$` instead of `Map` but accessing `MODULE$` by hand is unnecessary.

Comment: @Regis, according to my compiler, even the MODULE$ part is required, unfortunately.

Comment: Huh, weird. I'll have to check that. Sorry for the noise, I should try to refrain from posting without having a compiler at hand for verification.

Comment: The generics parameters should go before the function name: `scala.collection.immutable.Map$.MODULE$.<String, String>empty();`

Comment: Is there a way I can put <key, value> pairs in this immutable map while creating it? Basically I donot want an empty map instead immutable map with some default values, but I want to do it in java. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

At first I was puzzled that just doing the following would fail:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map<Integer, String> = scala.collection.immutable.Map$.<Integer, String>empty();
```

The reason it seemed odd is because I know for a fact that scala generates static forwarders that internally dereference `MODULE$` and call the corresponding (non-static) method.
I made some tests, and although what I found is somewhat tangential to the original question, it is still related and good to know.

Say we have the following:

```
package test
object MyScalaObject {
  def empty[A, B]: Map[A, B] = sys.error("TODO")
}
```

Using `javap` we can see that a static forwarder is generated:

```
public class test.MyScalaObject extends java.lang.Object{
    public static scala.collection.immutable.Map empty();
    public test.MyScalaObject();
}
```

And indeed we can in java just do the following:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map<Integer, String> myMap = test.MyScalaObject.<Integer, String>empty();
```

All is well and nice.
However, if we add a class or trait `MyScalaObject` that also defines a method with the same signature, no static forwarder is generated by scala (certainly because the JVM does not allow a class to define both a static and non-static method with the same signature). There are probably other different subtle situations that prevent the static forwarders to be generated.

Consider:

```
package test
class MyScalaObject {
  def empty[A, B]: Map[A, B] = sys.error("TODO")
}
object MyScalaObject {
  def empty[A, B]: Map[A, B] = sys.error("TODO TOO")
}
```

`javap` shows that the static forwarder has indeed disappeared:

```
public class test.MyScalaObject extends java.lang.Object{
    public scala.collection.immutable.Map empty();
    public test.MyScalaObject();
}
```

In this case it means that we have to explictly dereference `$MODULE` which points to the (unique) instance of the singleton object:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map<Integer, String> myMap = test.MyScalaObject$.MODULE$.<Integer, String>empty();
```

As it turns out, both the trait `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and its companion object define a parameterless `empty` method, so we stumble upon this very issue.

The moral is that while static forwarders are a potentially useful feature, it is also very fragile because the mere fact of modifying a class (in this case adding an `empty` method in class `MyScalaObject`) can break the feature, without even touching its companion object itself. It is thus certainly a good idea to always explicitly reference `MODULE$` (as in Wilfred Springer's answer) even if it looks less nice and even if the static forwarder is **currently** present, to prevent potential breakage when updating to a newer version of the library.